# Evaluate the angle x in terms of angles and y and z?

Tags: geometry

I need help with this problem and problems like this. I know that to solve this problem I have to find which angles are the same and etc, but how do I know that. How can I see that two angles are the same or if their sum is a certain angle ?

For example like this problem:

> In the following figure,AB ̅and ̅̅̅̅CD are parallel. Evaluate the angle x in terms of angles y and z.

[image]

How do I approach this problem ? Can you give me some tips for these types of problems ? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If AB and CD are parallel then that implies BD extended forms the same angle of intersection with them at both ends.  The same goes for AC.

Comment: Start by drawing it out, extending AB, AC and BD, and writing in the missing angles which are equal to others.  you will also use 2 rules: sum of angles within a triangle is 180 degrees, and sum of angles on a straight line is 180 degrees.

Comment: @RobertFrost So the y angle at point B is equal to the angle at point D ?

Comment: Yes, the higher of the two angles by D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x=z+y$

If you extend AB, BD and AC you will se that the angle outside of B is $y$.

Since AB and DC are parallel, the internal angle next to D and inside the triangle with $z$ is equal to $y$.

The angle next to $x$ and inside the triangle with $z$ is therefore $180-(z+y)$

$x$ is therefore $z+y$.

Comment: The moment you posted the question I figured it out hahaha. Thank you for the tips :D

Answer (score 1):

Label angle $CDB$ as $y$ and use the exterior angle theorem for triangles in Euclidean geometry.